# What is the easiest way to change element in the list Kotlin?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I got a list of objects `Exercize()`. So it contains `Exercize(time=9,name=pushup), Exercize(time=10,name=run),Exercize(time=12,name=swim)`. After click I got an item for example `Exercize(time=10, name=burpy)` so I need to find in the list the object with the same `time` and change it in the list. So as a result my list will be `Exercize()`. So it contains `Exercize(time=9,name=pushup), Exercize(time=10,name=burpy),Exercize(time=12,name=swim)`

How I can make it easier in kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming Exercise is an immutable class.

You can search for the index of the item to replace with `indexOfFirst`. If the index returned is negative, it means nothing fit the predicate. I suppose in that case you might just want to add the new item instead of swapping it in. Or maybe you would want to throw an error.

```
val exercisesList = mutableListOf(
    Exercize(time=9,name="pushup"), 
    Exercize(time=10,name="run"),
    Exercize(time=12,name="swim")
)
val burpee = Exercize(time=10,name="burpee")
val foundIndex = exercisesList.indexOfFirst { it.name == burpee.name }
if (foundIndex >= 0) {
    exercisesList[foundIndex] = burpee
} else {
    exercisesList += burpee
}
```

Maybe you were hoping for something shorter, but Kotlin doesn't provide many MutableList operators in the standard library. You could make this into one like this:

```
inline fun <T> MutableList.replaceFirstOrAdd(item: T, predicate: (T)->Boolean) {
    val index = indexOfFirst(predicate)
    if (index >= 0) {
        this[index] = item
    } else {
        add(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Code to update item in the list by specific property:

```
list.find { it.id == newItem.id }?.name = newItem.name
```

Full code example based on your answer:

```
val listOfExercizes = listOf(
    Exercize(time = 9, name = "pushup"),
    Exercize(time = 10, name = "run"),
    Exercize(time = 12, name = "swim")
)
println("List before changes: $listOfExercizes")

val newExercize = Exercize(time = 10, name = "burpy")

listOfExercizes.find { it.time == newExercize.time }?.name = newExercize.name

println("List after changes: $listOfExercizes")
```

Having next model class:

```
data class Exercize(val time: Int, var name: String)
```

Comment: so why here name became var? and can you explain the logic of solution?

Comment: You wrote that you need to change related item in the list: "I need to find in the list the object with the same time and change it in the list". So, if you want to update item property - those property should be mutable (initialized with var).

Comment: The logic is simple: we find item with proper time property in the list, and update it